# Declaring and initializing an integer pointer

Tags: go

I'm new to developing in Go. It seems like, though you're able to initialize a dictionary, structure, etc.. with a value (using curly-brackets), the same syntax can not be used to initialize an integer (all scalars?) pointer with a value. It might be because the curly bracket syntax seem to lend itself exclusively to [composite?] types.

Invalid due to "new(int) is not a type" error:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x int = 5
    var y *int = new(int){x}

    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

So, *is* there a way to initialize an integer with a reference to another variable, or does this necessarily always have to be separate steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to be verbose in assignments with go.

```
x := 5
y := &x
```

`x` will be created and initialized as an `int` and `y` will be `*int` upon compilation.

NOTE:  Because multiple assignment is processed as a single expression, `x, y := 5, &x` will **not** work.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm looking for an answer to the question as stated.

Comment: Please clarify the confusion.  The code I posted is the shortest way to initialize an integer and a pointer to that integer variable.

Comment: I'm aware of how your version works. I want to learn how to do it with *var*. This is not to say that I don't prefer the inferred-type syntax, but I want to get the question answered.

Comment: `var y *int = &x` creates `y` as a pointer to `x`.  There's no need for `new` for references to initialized variables.

Comment: Shoot. You're right. Eventually I was in the mindset of assigning a static integer before I realized that you had direct memory access with Go. When I realized that was the case, I switched to asking about how to initialize a new pointer with a reference but kept the same syntax that I was attempting for the static value. Thanks.